# What is the use of `,` and `,@` in Racket?

Tags: racket, dr.racket

I'm new to Racket and I was hoping to get more insights in the these two operators: `,` & `,@`.
There's very little documentation of these new operators, however, to my understanding the former (`,`) unquotes everything if its is followed by a list. And the latter (`,@`) splices the values.

For example if the following is typed in the Dr. Racket interpreter:

```
(define scores '(1 3 2))
(define pets '(dog cat))
```

and then the following query is made:

```
`(,scores ,@pets)
```

this would yield : `'((1 3 2) dog cat)`

It would be appreciated if I could get more details, definitions and more examples about these operators.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single quote followed by the written representation of a value
will produce that value:

Example:
'(1 x "foo")
will produce a value that prints as `(1 x "foo")`.

Suppose now that I don't want a literal symbol `x` in the list.
I have a variable `x` in my program, and I want to insert
the value to which `x` is bound.

To mark that I want the value of `x` rather than the symbol `x`,
I insert a comma before `x`:

```
'(1 ,x "foo")
```

It won't work as-is though - I now get a value that has a literal comma as well as a symbol `x`. The problem is that `quote` does not know about the comma convention.

Backtick or `backquote` knows about the comma-convention, so that will give the correct result:

```
> `(1 ,x "foo")
(1 3 "foo")          ; if the value of x is 3
```

Now let's say x is the list `(a b)`.

```
> `(1 ,x "foo")
(1 (a b) "foo")          ; if the value of x is (a b)
```

This looks as expected. But what if I wanted `(1 a b "foo")`
as the result? We need a way so show "insert the elements of a list".
That's where `,@` comes into the picture.

```
> `(1 ,@x "foo")
(1 a b "foo")          ; if the value of x is (a b)
```

Answer (score 2):

They are "reader abbreviations" or "reader macros". They are introduced in the [section of the Racket guide on quasiquotation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/qq.html). To summarize:

```
`e     reads as   (quasiquote e)
,e     reads as   (unquote e)
,@e    reads as   (unquote-splicing e)
```

Because Racket's printer uses the same abbreviations by default, it can be confusing to test this yourself. Here are a few examples that should help:

```
> (equal? (list 'unquote 'abc) (read (open-input-string ",abc")))
#t
> (writeln (read (open-input-string ",abc")))
(unquote abc)
```

A more exhaustive description of the Racket reader is in the [section on The Reader in the Racket Reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html). A list of reader abbreviations is in the [Reading Quotes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._parse-quote%29) subsection.